# Subtracting Value of rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building a stopwatch, in my app everything is working fine except the lap time. I have looked everywhere, but I can't figure out how to do it.
in my UITableView every row contains the split time. and what i need actually is the lap time which will be the 2nd split time - 1st split time = 1st lap time.

here is my code.

```
NSArray *arr1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *final1 = [arr1 lastObject];
        NSArray *finalArray1 = [final1 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        NSString *str2 = arrsplit[0];
        NSArray *arr2 = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *final2 = [arr2 lastObject];
        NSArray *finalArray2 = [final2 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        hours = [finalArray1[0] intValue] - [finalArray2[0] intValue];
        minutes = [finalArray1[1] intValue] - [finalArray2[1] intValue];
        seconds = [finalArray1[2] intValue] - [finalArray2[2] intValue];

        NSString *strlap =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

someone please help me out. thanx for your time.

Comment: So all you want to is how to subtract 00:00:05 - 00:00:02?

Comment: @rptwsthi   yes only that subtraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrsplit Try this .....

```
NSString *str1 = arrsplit[1];
NSArray *arr1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *final1 = [arr1 lastObject];
NSArray *finalArray1 = [final1 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSString *str2 = arrsplit[0];
NSArray *arr2 = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *final2 = [arr2 lastObject];
NSArray *finalArray2 = [final2 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

int hour = [finalArray1[0] intValue] - [finalArray2[0] intValue];
int min = [finalArray1[1] intValue] - [finalArray2[1] intValue];
int sec = [finalArray1[2] intValue] - [finalArray2[2] intValue];

NSString *lap =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, min, sec];
```

replace this function

```
- (IBAction)Split:(id)sender {


if (_Timer != nil) {
    int seconds = _currenttimeinsecond % 60;
    int minutes = (_currenttimeinsecond / 60) % 60;
    int hours = _currenttimeinsecond / 3600;

    NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Split %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    [arrsplit addObject:str];

    for(int i = 1 ; i < arrsplit.count; i++){
        NSString *str1 = arrsplit[i];

        NSArray *arr1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *final1 = [arr1 lastObject];
        NSArray *finalArray1 = [final1 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        NSString *str2 = arrsplit[i-1];
        NSArray *arr2 = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *final2 = [arr2 lastObject];
        NSArray *finalArray2 = [final2 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        hours = [finalArray1[0] intValue] - [finalArray2[0] intValue];
        minutes = [finalArray1[1] intValue] - [finalArray2[1] intValue];
        seconds = [finalArray1[2] intValue] - [finalArray2[2] intValue];

        NSString *strlap =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

        [arrlap addObject:strlap];
    }

    [tbl reloadData];
}

}
```

and also replace this to avoid crash

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.splitlabel.text = arrsplit[indexPath.row];
cell.laplabel.text =indexPath.row<arrlap.count? arrlap[indexPath.row]:@"";
return cell;
}
```

Comment: thnx kavya but its not working properly . its showing same time for first lap time and first split time.

Comment: just tell me your logic, where you are retrieving split time to calculate lap

Comment: here it is 
`(IBAction)Split:(id)sender { if (_Timer != nil)
 { int seconds = _currenttimeinsecond % 60; 
int minutes = (_currenttimeinsecond / 60) % 60; 
int hours = _currenttimeinsecond / 3600; 
NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Split %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds]; [arrsplit addObject:str]; 
[tbl reloadData];
}}`
 so array arrsplit containing all split time. and i am just showing these in a table view. so the only thing i have to do is to subtract the value of first row of table from the second row. then i'll get my lap time

Comment: @PriyantaSingh Please try to use updated answer n let me know

Comment: hey @kavya thanx for helping me . but now i am getting this error 

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`

Comment: check count of your arrsplit array

Comment: hey @Kavya   i have updated my question with my ViewController.m  , please see once where i am doing wrong.
 thanx for your time

Comment: @PriyantaSingh According to your formula to calculate lap "2nd split time - 1st split time = 1st lap time." last row lap label always remain empty.

Comment: ...  then how i can get this ? any idea @Kavya ??

Comment: can you tell me the line

Comment: which line ? i did't get you.

Comment: line where you getting this error ..... you can debug code in cellforrowatindexpath and split: function you will get that line

Comment: i can see after   `for(int i = 1 ; i < arrsplit.count; i++){
            NSString *str1 = arrsplit[i];`    
Table gets reloaded.

Comment: its working now. not getting any error. but always returning same lap time.

Comment: please send me screen shot, if split time entries are after same interval then in that case my calculation will print same value. just send me screenshot

Comment: Hey I have checked, its working properly. If you want calculate laptime then you have to use split arrat right?

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 things, instead of adding formatted string add `_currenttimeinsecond` in array as `[arrsplit addObject:@(_currenttimeinsecond)]`;

Now since you have that you can always populate that in your cell using same method you use now to format it.

By this way it will be easy for you to calculate the subtraction:

```
int lap = arrsplit[i] - arrsplit[i-1];
```

Hope this will help.